# Django DRY verbose names with foreign keys?

Tags: python, django

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'my awesome name'

class ModelB(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

Is there a way to make `some_field`'s verbose_name to be `my awesome name` without being explicit about it? (ie. using the verbose name related class as a default field verbose name, instead of using the attribute name)
I actually think this should be the default Django behaviour.

NOTE: I'm using Django 1.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking into the source code it seems like this is implemented in the [`set_attributes_from_rel`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L381) method of the `RelatedField` class:

```
if self.verbose_name is None:
    self.verbose_name = self.remote_field.model._meta.verbose_name
```

The `verbose_name` is also set in the [`set_attributes_from_name`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L724) method from the `Field` class:

```
if self.verbose_name is None and self.name:
    self.verbose_name = self.name.replace('_', ' ')
```

This method is run first and therefore when the method of the `RelatedField` class is run `self.verbose_name` is no longer `None`. It is unclear to me why the method of the `Field` class is run first.

Note: I checked the current source code on GitHub which is most likely a newer version than your code as your `ForeignKey` doesn't have the `on_delete` parameter which was made required in version 2.0.

Comment: Excellent answer! But go further: what to do? Define a custom `ForeignKey` class?

Comment: A discussion about this can be found in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5373#comment:30). Sadly the status is `wontfix` due to not backwards compatible, but the comments give another option by supplying verbose_name as `verbose_name=ModelA._meta.verbose_name`.

Comment: @ikkuh Thanks a lot for your investigation :) From what I understood in the talks, this worked initally, but they broke it at some point for another feature, ans then, didn't find useful to fix it, seems there is the `_meta` workaround, which is an acceptable solution.